# Personal Hotspot feature on IPad 2

Tags: ipad, tethering

I am not able to set-up Personal Hotspot in my IPad 2. I have read somewhere that, if my carrier allows me to enable Hotspot, then the IPad also will allow me to enable Hotspot, as Apple has no correspondence with the Hotspot. But, when I connect the same SIM card to my IPhone, the hotspot works. So, is there any way I can enable Hotspot in my IPad?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Apple Support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4517) the personal hotspot feature is only available from the third generation iPad upwards.

> Learn how to share your cellular data connection using Personal Hotspot, the Internet-sharing feature on iPhone, iPad (3rd generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular or later, and iPad mini Wi-Fi + Cellular.